# Django url obfuscate with GET parameters

Tags: python, django, url, obfuscation

I have been using [django-unfriendly](http://django-unfriendly.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to obfuscate urls but it seems to work only with URLs without GET parameters like:
`http://yoursite.com/music/awesome/the-melvins/`
and then it transforms to:
`http://yoursite.com/u/E5v4uxuNSA8I2is33c6V8lqFTcdv_IxPLDGG/` as the link explains.

I need to send GET parameters with the obfuscated URL like

`http://yoursite.com/u/E5v4uxuNSA8I2is33c6V8lqFTcdv_IxPLDGG/?param=Hello&param2=Bye`

But when I debug the request, the URL is passing without any parameter, it seems like they were ignored in the deobfuscation process.

Any suggestions to make this work? Maybe another option?

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/tomatohater/django-unfriendly/blob/develop/unfriendly/views.py#L38) though, it actually tries to preserve the url query parameters..

Comment: yeah, it seems to preserve the parameters, but it only preserves POST params, not GET, I dont know why, I am using Django 1.8+ by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
environ['QUERY_STRING'] = query
```

with

`from urllib import urlencode`

`environ['QUERY_STRING'] = query + urlencode(request.GET) if request.GET.items() else ''`

In deobfuscate function of unfirendly views solved it.